# Socket.io rooms based on /link

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I would like to implement rooms for chatting in my `node.js` project using `socket.io`. I would like to create a room based on any forward slash link visited that all people who access that link are joined in that rooms.

For example:

If my website is `nodeapp.com`, a room can be created by going to `nodeapp.com/funroom`. Anyone who goes to `nodeapp.com/funroom` (while there is at least 1 person in the room) can globally chat.

I do not need help implementing chat, just rooms.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

1) You need send room name to server:

```
// Client
var socket = io('/');
socket.emit('joinroom', window.location.pathname);
socket.on("new user", function(data) {
    console.log("New user. Total users: ", data);
});
```

2) You need get room name on server and join:

```
// Backend
var io = require('socket.io')();
var rooms = {};
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('joinroom', function(room) {
        this.join(room);
        if (typeof rooms[room] ==== "undefined") rooms[room] = {};
        rooms[room].count = rooms[room].total ? rooms[room].total+1 : 1; 
        io.to(room).emit("new user", rooms[room].count)
    });
});
```

Comment: it says cannot get /whateverIEnter

Answer (score 1):

I have written a similar app for my university, using the following setup:

A user browses to `nodeapp.com/desiredRoom`. My express server has the following route:

```
app.get("/:roomName", function(res, req){
    res.render("student", {room:req.params.roomName});
})
```

This renders a template (using Jade), with the input parameter `room` defined by the URL. I then pass this parameter to the client as a javascript variable. The Jade template looks something like this:

```
html
    head
        script.
            room="#{room}";     
            script(src='/clientScript.js');
body
    ...
```

On the client side, `clientScript.js` now knows what room to join. You can use this system to perform more advanced room requests. For example, I split up the rooms based on multiple parameters in the URL.